# Scala splitting a sting before adding it to a Sorted Set

Tags: scala

I need to split all values from a table with respect to white space and finally add them to a List/ Collection.

My Code

```
val keywords = scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet[String]()
val connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql:<Conn Details>", "<DBNAME>", "<PASSWD>")
val rs = connection.createStatement()
val res = rs.executeQuery("select nom from ip.interest_points where in_use = cast(1 as bit)")
while (res.next) {
  keywords += res.getString("nom")
}
print (keywords)
```

Returns

```
TreeSet(AOC Les Halles, Adele - Réseau Art Contemporain Lyon 
Métropole, Amphithéâtre des Trois Gaules, Ancien Hôpital de
l'Antiquaille, Ancienne Gare des Brotteaux...)
```

I want to split the values from "nom" followed by appending it to the keywords Sorted Set.

```
keywords += res.getString("nom").split(" ")
```

Above code is what I tried and it did not work.

Expected output

```
TreeSet(AOC,Les,Halles, Adele,-,Réseau,Art,Contemporain,Lyon...)
```

Edit :

```
keywords += res.getString("nom").split(" ").toString

gives ([Ljava.lang.String;@ff5b51f .... )
```

Comment: What's the type of `keywords` and what's the type of `res.getString("nom").split(" ")`?

Comment: I get a compile time error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.split() returns an `Array`. You can't `+=` a SortedSet and an Array. Make a new SortedSet with all the values of the first one and then add the two Sets.
Something like this:

```
while (res.next) {
   val names = scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet[String]()
   val interestPoints = res.getString("nom").split(" ")
   for (interestPoint <- interestPoints ){
     names += interestPoint
   }
   keywords = keywords ++ names
}
```

Or something like this:

```
while (res.next) {
   val interestPoints = res.getString("nom").split(" ")
   keywords ++= interestPoints 
}
```

`+` is usually for adding a single element to a collection and `++` is usually for concatenating two collections.

If you're using immutable collections, I know that `ArrayOps` has a method `toSet` which converts to a immutable Set.

Comment: Let me try this.Thanks for replying

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on the syntax of mutable collections, since I usually use the immutable ones, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to write java code in scala. :)

I think, if you tried to stay idiomatic, and take advantage of the native features of language you are using, you would find, that a lot of things, that seemed tedious and hard to do are becoming simple and elegant.

Something like this perhaps:

```
new Iterator[String] {
  def hasNext = res.next
  def next = res.getString("nom")
}
.flatMap(_.split(" "))
.to[SortedSet]
```